# Magento 2.1: How to set some conditions before checkout

Tags: magento2, orders

I'm newbie in Magento 2. I have an problem with my shop. I need to check programmtically some conditions before the user placing some orders.

```
if(condition)
     placeOrder()/saveOrder()
else
     sorry! order can't be created.
```

Has somebody an idea how and where can i do it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an observer before the order is placed with this event `sales_order_place_before` and put your custom logic.